# How to simulate Ubuntu ARM image on Raspberry Pi with Virtualbox?

Tags: emulation, arm

How do you run the [Ubuntu ARM image](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) in Virtualbox (ultimately managed through Vagrant) for testing a Raspberry Pi configuration?

I can find a ton of [guides](http://ediy.com.my/index.php/blog/item/52-virtualbox-raspberry-pi-emulator) for running various pre-built Raspberry Pi images in Virtualbox, but they all use Raspbian or Windows images and don't explain where those "ova" files came from, much less how they were created.

Comment: Where are you planning to run virtualbox? On the Pi or an Ubuntu PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox doesn't support the emulation of other architecture types. Virtualizing an operating system of the same architecture is fundamentally different than that of another. My guess is that the provided images are of Raspbian re-compiled for `x86`, or more likely, another distro simply recompiled to be more Raspbianish.

Personally, I wouldn't load the `ova` files linked to in your guide; they seem sketchy.